# How to create one migration file for one model file in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

In a django app i created models folder, in which folder contains multiple model files,

When i run command `python manange.py makemigrations <app_name>`, it generates one migration file for all the *.py models.

So, is this possible to generate multiple migration files for multiple *.py models.

Comment: Why are you storing your models in a folder instead of one file?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package

Comment: Why to do you want multiple migration files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. And there is no reason to do so. However, if you want to have multiple files for some obscure reason, you can still manually split the generated migration into multiple migrations *before* apply them with `migrate` (for instance, create an empty migration with `--empty` option and move the operations you want to this empty migration). Alternatively, you can pay attention to run `makemigrations` before modifying another models file.

But again, I don't see any reason to have multiple migrations when you can have only one.